# I need a larger array than max heap space

Tags: java, arrays, heap-memory

I am writing a program that requires an array of integers with 500 million elements. However, my maximum heap space is too small. I cannot split it in to many smaller arrays and use one at a time or increase my heap size. What can I do?

Comment: Are you using a 32 or 64 bit JVM? On 32 bit, the limit is 4GB, which is reached already when you make an array of that size. 64 bit allows you to allocate a multitude of that amount.

Comment: In order for us to help suggest viable alternatives, you'll have to explain a bit more of why you need all those numbers in memory at the same time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm using 64 bit. I have a 64 bit computer and Java's in Program Files(x86). I probably could come up with a way around using the array, but I've already written the code to work with it and it increases calculation speed. I used lower indexed elements in the array to calculate the higher indexed ones. I then loop through the array and add up certain values.

Comment: There is probably a size limit for an individual object that is on the order of 2-4GB, even on a 64-bit JVM

Comment: Program Files(x86) is for 32-bit programs.

Comment: Please post the output of `java -version`.

Comment: java -version gives me : java version "1.8.0_51" Java(TM) SE Runtime Enviroment (build 1.8.0_51-b16) Java Hotspot(TM) Client VM (build 25.52-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I'm using the array for a sieve

Comment: That indicates a 32-bit JVM.

Answer (score 2):

I have just tested something similar on 1.7.0_79 64-bit Linux, using the following test program:

```
class T {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int array[] = new int[Integer.parseInt(args[0])];
        for (int i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = array[i-1] + 1;
        }
        System.err.println("last value: " + array[array.length-1]);
    }
}
```

It takes as an argument the size of the int array to reserve. By my back-of-the-envelope math, 500M ints is around 1.86GB (using 4-byte ints), not accounting for VM overhead. So to test this:

```
javac T.java && java -Xmx2G T 500000000

-> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
           at T.main(T.java:3)
```

So too small; Increasing the heap size further:

```
javac T.java && java -Xmx3G T 500000000

-> last value: 499999999
```

So either you are not using a 64-bit VM, or you are not requesting enough space to be reserved.

Edit: for what it's worth, on my machine, I need to set -Xmx2870M or more to avoid the OOME. With -Xmx2860M it still fails.

Comment: I ran it with -Xmx3g and got the error 
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 3145728KB object heap. 
I have 12 gigabytes of RAM though